# App crashes after add a new content to html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress-mvc

I need to reload `GridView` on the tab click event. I wrote the next code:

```
<script>
    function OnTabClickEvent(s, e) {
        var tableUrl;

        switch (e.tab.Index) {
            case 0:
                tableUrl = '@Url.Action("CGridViewPartial", "Competences")';
                break;
            default:
                tableUrl = '@Url.Action("TGridViewPartial", "Technologies")';
        }

        $('#TabContent').empty();
        $('#TabContent').load(tableUrl);
    }
</script>

<div>
    @Html.DevExpress().TabControl(settings => 
    {
        settings.Name = "CatalogTabControl";
        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

        settings.Tabs.Add(tab =>
        {
            tab.Name = "TabCompetences";
            tab.Text = Headers.Competences;
        });
        settings.Tabs.Add(tab =>
        {
            tab.Name = "TabProjects";
            tab.Text = Headers.ProjectsActivities;
        });
        settings.Tabs.Add(tab =>
        {
            tab.Name = "TabTechnologies";
            tab.Text = Headers.Technologies;
        });

        //Events
        settings.ClientSideEvents.TabClick = "OnTabClickEvent";
    }).GetHtml()
</div>
<div id="TabContent">
    @Html.Action("CGridViewPartial", "Competences")
</div>
```

It works but only once... On the second click it crashes with errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FindEventSourceParentByTestFunc' of undefined Page:74 Uncaught
>   TypeError: ASPx.TCTClick is not a function

What do I doing wrong? I really can't understand why it doesn't work on the second and next tab clicks.

Comment: is this a javascript error or a .NET error? Looks like javascript but just wanted to be sure. If it is, you probably need to post the related javascript code. Your browser should be able to tell you the line where the error is occuring

Comment: This is an error in JavaScript that contains in default scripts. And that is interesting this bug appears only if I add a new content to page, not on removing.

Comment: "default scripts". Which scripts exactly? There are no default scripts in a browser, only those added by you or by the MVC framework. It would help to know the location of the error.

Comment: I can't fix these problems so I reverted all devexpress views on this page. I can't post a full information now, unfortunately. I will vote up to close the topic

Comment: DevExpress? See this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T317522 sounds like a similar error. Maybe you need to configure the plugin properly. I haven't used it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function OnTabClickEvent(s, e) {
        var tableUrl;

        switch (e.tab.Index) {
            case 0:
                tableUrl = CGridView.PerformCallback(); // where CGridView is the name of the grid view
                break;
            default:
                tableUrl = TGridView.PerformCallback(); // where TGridView is the name of the grid view
        }

    }
</script>
```

Read more about callbacks here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9052